# Можно ли узнать с помощью JS кол-во открытых вкладок?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет полуночники.
Можно ли узнать с помощью JavaScript кол-во открытых вкладок хрома(моих,которые открыты в моём браузере)?

p.s. если что я их открываю с помощью скрипта каждые 2 сек.,а после закрываю,если не нахожу для себя кое-чего интересного.Но дело в том,что сайт иногда проружается долго и вкладок накапливается очень много.

Или может ещё какие решения будут?

Comment: Думаю, нельзя. Это часть privacy пользователя, информацию о том, что пользователь делает вне вашего сайта вам вряд ли даст браузер по доброй воле.

Comment: Ну и вряд ли открывать новую вкладку каждые 2 секунды можно назвать дружественным к пользователю поведением.

Comment: Вы не поняли,у меня нету сайта. 
Я хочу узнать кол-во своих вкладок на моём компьютере.
И при лимите(например 20 вкладок) сделать паузу в своём скрипте.

Comment: А, на _вашем_ компьютере! Окей, тогда вам по идее нужен userscript. В файрфоксе я видел подобное, как именно в хроме, не знаю. Но наверняка можно.

Comment: У расширений есть такая возможность. Написать вроде не сложно https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

Comment: userscript это вы про tamperMonkey?(расширение для выполнения яваскриптов?) так я с помощь него и открываю эти вкладки.

Только не знаю,как можно подсчитать количество открытых.гугл выдаёт не то.

Comment: @ThreegunD: Он самый.

Comment: @VladD так вот,я это и хотел узнать,как это делается,если вообще реально.

Comment: @ThreegunD: Ну, вам же @dzhioev дал ссылку на документацию. `chrome.tabs` даёт коллекцию всех табов. Как узнать количество элементов коллекции, вы должны знать лучше меня (я полный ноль в JS).

Comment: @VladD, я не про tampermonkey писал, а про chrome extension. Насколько я понимаю, tampermonkey просто инжектит пользовательские скрипты в страницы, но в контексте страницы оперировать вкладками нельзя.

Comment: @VladD ,dzhioev спасибо,буду "копать" в этом направлении.

Comment: @dzhioev: Я не знаю насчёт tampermonkey, но greasemonkey под FF выполняет скрипты в привилегированной области, в которой они имеют доступ к внутренним объектам и XUL'у самого браузера. (Но насколько я понимаю не в области полного доступа.)

Comment: Вам надо  сделать собственное расширение для хрома, ни в какие магазины его выкладывать не надо. все запускается с собственного компа. Галочку "режим разработчика" в меню расширений ставите и все. Открываете ту документацию, что вам выше сказали, там есть ссылки Samples, там есть примеры. А потом думаете не выбросить ли tampermonkey, без него средствами самого хром-екстеншена все делается

Comment: @Mike: А разве написать простой скрипт под tampermonkey не проще, чем целое расширение? (Под лисичку это так и есть.)

Comment: @VladD Расширение от скрипта отличается одним небольшим xml в котором написано название расширения, описаны входящие в него JS. И к чему оно имеет доступ. Т.е. на пару строк больше, чем описание в начале скрипта под обезьян. И вместо нескольких функций обезьян использовать несколько функций хрома. зато возможностей гораздо больше

Comment: @Mike: Ого! Минимальное расширение под FF выглядит как-то так: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/The_Essentials_of_an_Extension (и это намного больше, чем один файл).